# How to prove that $\limsup \{a_n\}=-\liminf \{-a_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

How to show that

$\limsup \{a_n\}=-\liminf \{-a_n\}$

I could use this property : if $a= \sup(X) $ then, $-a=\inf(-X)$?

where

$\lim\sup\{a_n\}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\sup\{a_k\,|\,k\geq
n\}]$

$\liminf\{a_n\}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\inf\{a_k\,|\,k\geq
n\}]$

Comment: What is the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ you are using?

Comment: edited question,  definition of lim suplim sup and lim inflim inf

Comment: You might try to show it very explicitly.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\liminf x_n = -\limsup (-x_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/334114) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/334114).

Comment: Doesn't the property you stated more or less immediately imply the claim?