# If $\{a_n\}$ is bounded sequence , prove that $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=-\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}(-a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> If $\{a_n\}$ is bounded sequence, prove that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n=-
> \liminf _{n\to \infty} (-a_n)$$

**My Attempt:**

\begin{align}
\liminf_{n \to \infty} (-a_n)&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf(-a_n,-a_{n+1},....)\\
&=\lim _{n \to \infty} (-\sup (a_n,a_{n+1},....))\\
&=-\lim _{n \to \infty}\sup (a_n,a_{n+1},....)
\end{align}

hence

$\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=-\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}(-a_n)$

Is this attempt right?

Comment: If you have already proven that $\sup A=-\inf(-A)$ for an upward bounded set $A$ then yes. Also note that `\liminf,  \limsup, \inf` and `\sup` are existing commands.

Comment: @Arthur...what i understand with your comment is first we need to prove $\sup A=-\inf(-A)$

Comment: Question body and question title do not match.

Comment: @KennyLau...sorry i edited now thanks for point me

Comment: Yes, you need to prove that, because that's what you're using when you say $\inf(-a_n,-a_{n+1},\ldots) =-\sup (a_n,a_{n+1},\ldots)$.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\liminf x_n = -\limsup (-x_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/334114) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/334114).

Comment: If the main purpose of your question is to ask for verification and criticism of your own proof (as opposed to asking for any proof of this claim), then you should use ([tag:proof-verification]) tag. See also [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info).